# Outlook Ribbon Load Inspector.CurrentItem is null

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

### Overview

I have an Outlook add-in created with VSTO. The add-in has a single ribbon (visual designer) for the `Mail.Compose` ribbon type. The ribbon tab `ControlIdType` is set to "Custom". The only code in the add-in other than designer code is the following `Load` handler for the ribbon. `this.Context.CurrentItem` is unexpectedly returning null.

### Code

```
private void RibbonComposeMail_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var inspector = this.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
        if (inspector == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Fail - Step 1");
        }

        var currentMailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (currentMailItem == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Fail - Step 2");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

### Steps

1. Open draft email. Ribbon loads OK.
2. Open email from inbox.
3. Open same draft email. Ribbon fails at step 2, `inspector.CurrentItem` is null.

### Notes

- I've tested this in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013, with an Outlook 2007 and 2010 add-in created in VS2010, and Outlook 2010 add-in created in VS2012. All behave the same.
- Repeatedly opening the draft email doesn't appear to cause the issue, an Email.Read inspector has to be opened in between.
- The ribbon tab `ControlidType` matters. "Custom" will cause the issue, but the default option of "Office" doesn't exhibit the issue.
- Flipping the scenario on its head and setting the ribbon type to `Mail.Read` gives the same result, provided the sequence of opening is reversed to Inbox > Draft > Inbox (fail).
- All possible permutations of calls to `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on the `inspector` and `currentMailItem` objects makes no difference.

Comment: Can anyone else at least replicate the error? As far as I can see I'm doing nothing wrong. This looks to be the accepted way to get the item associated with a ribbon, but it's failing! Even this VSTOTeam blog uses much the same technique - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/02/23/activate-ribbon-tabs-in-office-2010-solutions-norm-estabrook.aspx - I tried their code, which is only subtly different, and it too exhibited the error. Could this be a bug that's been kicking around un-noticed for the last 3 Outlook releases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mikes comments helped reveal to me something a little more curious about the behaviour. At step 1, the `RibbonComposeMail_Load` event is called *once*. But at step 3 it is called *twice*. The first time the event is called at step 3, `this.Context.CurrentItem` is null, but the second time the event is called, the property holds the email.

It was comparing item values in the `NewInspector` event with those in the ribbon `Load` event which made me notice this. Because the sequence of events at step 3 is: `Ribbon_Load`, `NewInspector`, `Ribbon_Load`. I was getting `Ribbon_Load` to `MessageBox.Show` the subject of the mail item in `ThisAddIn.CurrentMailItem`, but was quite surprised to see it was the subject of the **previous** email opened, i.e. the inbox email at step 2!

As it turns out, the solution then is to ignore everything in the `Ribbon_Load` event if `this.Context.CurrentItem` is null, because a second `Ribbon_Load` event is about to be triggered with the correct values set. As to *why* we see this strange behaviour in step 3 of my example, but not step 1? That's probably a question for the people the implemented the Outlook Object Model.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue myself.

I have designed a Ribbon Bar for Outlook Calendar appointments, with a few extra fields that I wanted to save with each appointment  (eg "Does this Meeting save travel ?")

I managed it, but, it was tricky to do.

As you've said, when your **Ribbon1_Load** function gets launched, the **ActiveInspector()** is null... so how are you supposed to get details about the current Email message or Calendar appointment ?

Here's what you need to do.  This example is based about Calendar appointments, but it's very easy to adapt to EmailItems instead.

First, in the ThisAddIn.cs file, you need to make a few changes:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
    public static Outlook.AppointmentItem theCurrentAppointment;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }
```

When the user opens or creates a new Outlook item, our "**Inspectors_NewInspector**" function will get called, and at that point, we *are* able to get details about the item:

```
void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
{
     //  This function (apparently) gets kicked off whenever a user opens a new or existing item
     //  in Outlook (Calendar appointment, Email, etc).  
     //  We can intercept it, modify it's properties, before letting our Ribbon know about it's existance.
     //
     theCurrentAppointment = null;

     object item = Inspector.CurrentItem;
     if (item == null)
         return;

     if (!(item is Outlook.AppointmentItem))
         return;

     theCurrentAppointment = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
}
```

With this code in place, we can adapt our **Ribbon1_Load** function to take this "theCurrentAppointment" variable, and read in details about the Calendar appointment which the user is creating/modifying.

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
     //  When this function gets called, "Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()" is always NULL, so we have
     //  to fetch the selected AppointmentItem via the ThisAddIn class.

     if (ThisAddIn.theCurrentAppointment != null)
     {
         //  Our Ribbon control contains a TextBox called "tbSubject"
         tbSubject.Text = ThisAddIn.theCurrentAppointment.Subject
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I had wondered if switching to an `Inspector` event handler / wrapper model would be the only option left to me, but investigating your proposed technique revealed a little more to me about what was going on. See my own answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds like the garbage collector have cleared your this.Context.

Could you try to put your Context in a private field and get the currentitem from it:

```
private readonly Context _context = new Context(); 


private void RibbonComposeMail_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var inspector = _context as Outlook.Inspector;
        if (inspector == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Fail - Step 1");
        }

        var currentMailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (currentMailItem == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Fail - Step 2");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help, i normaly use the Outlook.Application object to get the currentitem:

```
readonly Outlook._Application _application = new Outlook.Application();

var selectionList = _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

foreach (Object selObject in selectionList)
{
    if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        var outlookMail = (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
    }
}
```

Or if you only need the currentitem, as you do in your case:

```
var mailItem = _application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[0];
```

Comment: `this.Context` is a property of the `RibbonBase` class, it's not a class of my own creation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.context.aspx

Using `Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection` doesn't really add up either, as I'm using an `Inspector`, NOT an `Explorer`. There may not even be an active `Explorer` at load.

Comment: I also tried switching `this.Context as Outlook.Inspector` to `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()`, and interestingly enough, in the same scenarios where my code would have failed on step 2, it instead failed on step 1, meaning `ActiveInspector()` was null.