# How to get AppointmentID on a buttonclick

Tags: asp.net, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I have created an outlook add-in where i have a ribbon that adds a button to the appointment tab. This button has a callback method that opens IE and goes to a specific page.

What i need: When you create an appointmnet and ID is stored somewhere(i assume). 
I need to get the ID of the appointment that i have opend when i click on my button.

Simplify:

click on an appointment----->appointmnet has a costom button---->click the button--->open a page with the appointmentID.

I need to get the ID and add it to the url paramater when i open the page.

I have been reading up on the appointment global ID here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863645.aspx

And all the links that follow that article but I have not found anything that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im glad i have friends who know this better than me...
soloution here:

[Outlook Ribbon Load Inspector.CurrentItem is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458338/outlook-ribbon-load-inspector-currentitem-is-null)