# Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector == null although a valid Outlook.AppointmentItem is displayed why?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

i am developing an outlook plugin using VSTO.

in the method:
this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.MyApp_Load);

In MyApp_Load of my Ribbon I use the following code:

```
if (Globals.ThisAddIn.isLoggedIn())
{
    btnMyApp.Visible= true;
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = 
         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
    if (inspector != null && inspector.CurrentItem != null)
    {
```

When I open up an AppointmentItem in Outlook I can debug the code above. Unfortunately the ActiveInspector() == null although a valid AppointmentItem is being displayed.

Why?

Comment: I found this solution in Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458338/outlook-ribbon-load-inspector-currentitem-is-null/18767053

Answer (score 0):

That method is called before the inspector is displayed. You must use `RibbonUI` passed as an argument to your `onLoad` callback and cast `RibbonUI.Context` to the `Inspector` interface.